# Convert JSON file

Tags: pandas

I have a set of data in JSON format. From what I understand, JSON is not usable and I need to convert it into some kind of table format for me to use as a data set.

I have tried to convert the file to CSV. It works but it doesn't come out correctly. It ends up as without proper labelling and columns. Is there a way around this?

This is the data set example.

```
{
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "items": [
        "bar",
        "cream"
      ],
      "extras": {},
      "supply": "crate"
    }
}
```

This is what I did with Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json("myfile.json").to_csv("new.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `pd.read_json` with the proper `orient` parameter.

This is from the `read_json` [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html):

> orient : string,
>
> Indication of expected JSON string format. Compatible JSON strings can be produced by to_json() with a corresponding orient value. The set of possible orients is:
>
> 'split' : dict like {index -> [index], columns -> [columns], data -> [values]}
>
> 'records' : list like [{column -> value}, ... , {column -> value}]
>
> 'index' : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
>
> 'columns' : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
>
> 'values' : just the values array

In your case, I think `pd.read_json("myfile.json", orient="values")` should work.

If you have nested json fields, you will have to also use `pd.json_normalize()` to flatten the nested fields (consult [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)).