# How to convert this specific json file into a data frame?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file and I would like to convert it into a data frame with several columns (hour, frappucino, soda, coffee, tea, water, milkshake, nothing, sandwich, pie, muffin, cookie) and put the values at the right place.

If someone can help me, it would be great. :)

[image]

Comment: I'd be very surprised if that's a CSV. It looks like JSON.

Comment: Have you tried pd.read_json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON file for Sci kit Learn Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221047/convert-json-file-for-sci-kit-learn-processing)

Answer (score 0):

It's a JSON file. You should use `pd.read_json` to load it into a dataframe.
For example,

```
df = pd.read_json('yourfile.json')
```

Note that you need to select the correct `orient` parameter to match your specific JSON structure:

> orient : string,
>
> Indication of expected JSON string format. Compatible JSON strings can be produced by to_json() with a corresponding orient value. The set of possible orients is:
>
> 'split' : dict like {index -> [index], columns -> [columns], data -> [values]}
>
> 'records' : list like [{column -> value}, ... , {column -> value}]
>
> 'index' : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
>
> 'columns' : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
>
> 'values' : just the values array

In your case, I think it is `df = pd.read_json('yourfile.json', orient='index')`

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted but it's okay